# parse a string object to a JSONObject

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I need to parse a string that contains data of JSON file into a JSONObject and iterate over it's content to get it's keys and values for further treatement after. I'am stuck at parsing the content of a file after transforming it to a string. I tried to user parse() , quote() but it seems i'am missing a detail and i'am making a major mistake.

This is a snippet of the json file i treat :

```
{
    {
    "id":0,
    "name": "project1",
    "couverage": "100",
    "completness": "44.8",
    "consistency": "46",
    }
    
    {
    "id":1,
    "name": "project2",
    "couverage": "100",
    "completness": "44.8",
    "consistency": "46",
    }
    
    {
    "id":2,
    "name": "project3",
    "couverage": "100",
    "completness": "44.8",
    "consistency": "46",
    }
}
```

and this is the code i developed

```
public void readfromJsonFile(File jsonFile, long readTimeStamp) {
    logger.info("Read from JSON file:  {}", jsonFile.getName());
    
    try{
            
        //Read File Content
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(jsonFile.toPath()));
        
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser(content);
        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse();
        JSONArray key = obj.names();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < key.length (); ++i) {
            String keys = key.getString(i);
            System.out.println(keys);
            String value = obj.getString (keys);
            System.out.println(value);
    }catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Failed to parse JSON File: {}", jsonFile.getName());
        }
}
```

Comment: Your issue is while getting the key and the value?

Comment: Yes i cannot read my content string (or Json file)

Comment: Can I show one example with Jackson ? Would you appreciate that ?

Comment: @NabilZouita I can't figure out in which line you get problems.

Comment: @AnishB. Yes why not if it can help i would appreciate that

Comment: Ok I'm adding my answer. :)

Comment: @Ismail the problem is the for loop while iterrating on the file i cannot read it's content, my guess is i'am doing something wrong starting from this line:  jsonParser = new JSONParser(content);

Comment: @NabilZouita are you sure that the content String is getting the right JSON value from the file?

Comment: Yes @Ismail, if I try to print content string after this line String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(jsonFile.toPath())); i get displayed the same content in the JSON file

Comment: Is this json even correct, I don't see square brackets depicting it's an array or list. I don't see commas between each inner json section to separate elements. And even consistency have a comma in end, that too is wrong. This cannot even be called a json :)

Comment: @NabilZouita, First you have issues with the JSON format as mentioned above, secondly, could you give me an example of a key and value from your JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jackson Databind as well.

Create a POJO class. For example :

```
public class POJO {

   private int id;
   private String name;
   private String couverage;
   private String completness;
   private String consistency;

   // getters, setters and constructors

}
```

Modify the JSON in the file.

```
[
    {
    "id":0,
    "name": "project1",
    "couverage": "100",
    "completness": "44.8",
    "consistency": "46"
    },
    {
    "id":1,
    "name": "project2",
    "couverage": "100",
    "completness": "44.8",
    "consistency": "46"
    },
    {
    "id":2,
    "name": "project3",
    "couverage": "100",
    "completness": "44.8",
    "consistency": "46"
    }
]
```

Code :

```
public void readfromJsonFile(File jsonFile, long readTimeStamp) {
    logger.info("Read from JSON file:  {}", jsonFile.getName());
    try {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        POJO[] pojos = objectMapper.readValue(jsonFile, POJO[].class);
        for (int i = 0; i < pojos.length; ++i) {
            System.out.println(pojos[i].getId());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Failed to parse JSON File: {}", jsonFile.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: @NabilZouita Is this helpful ?

Comment: I have a model that will read those values (consistency, coverage, ...) can I use the model or I have to create a class with the attributes of the Json file ?

Comment: i spent some time testing but this was helpful thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
JSONArray array_= new JSONArray(content);
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) array_.get(0);// or any index
```

then you can use the Object.

Comment: still the same issue unfortunatly !